# Java: How to continue reading a file after an exception is thrown

Tags: java, io

so my professor has assigned us a project where we have to take in commands from a text file and use them to drive the flow of our program. These commands such as- Takeoff, land, load cargo, unload cargo, etc.- are meant to simulate an airplane-like object.

Sometimes these commands don't make sense to execute, like loading cargo while a plane is in-flight. Therefore, to prevent something like that from happening we had to code in our own exception classes i.e. **"If the plane is ordered to load cargo while in flight, throw InvalidActionException"**

My question is: how can I **continue** to read-in commands from the text file after exceptions have been thrown (seeing as how once they are thrown, the program cannot progress further

Here's an outline of what I want to do:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("stuff1.txt"));

    while(input.hasNextLine())
    {
        try 
        {
             //execute commands by reading them using input.nextLine()
        }
        catch()
        {
            //catch any exceptions and ignore them... continue to read
           //the file for more commands
        }
    }
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: If you catch the Exception then the program won't end abruptly.  Make sure you specify the correct Exception class in your catch statement.

Comment: Just put the exception you want to catch between the parentheses after the catch clause, and you have your solution: catch (InvalidCommandException e) { // ignore }

Comment: Do you really want to continue processing the file when you know it is garbage??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Catch` appropriate exception and flow will automatically reach `while` loop condition.

After cathing exception nothing extra to be done to continue the program.

Answer (score 3):

> seeing as how once they are thrown, the program ends abruptly

Only uncaught exception stop a thread.  I suggest you catch all the exceptions you want to continue after and you won't have a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Catch your specific exception:

```
while(input.hasNextLine())
{
    try 
    {
         //execute commands by reading them using input.nextLine()
    }
    catch ( UserDefinedException ex )
    {
         //catch the exceptions you're throwing
    }
}
```

Comment: Better not to do it in the loop as suggested by @Graham Borland.

Comment: @Mudassir but that's what the op wants, for the loop to continue. Graham doesn't suggest that, he's merely stating what happens.

Comment: @Mudassir: It has to be inside while cause OP wants to read next line after exception occurs.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore: Sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

That's exactly what you want to do. All the reading and processing statements go in the `try` block, and the `catch` block just contains error processing (which may consist of nothing other than printing a warning message somewhere.

The thing you need to be careful of is that you don't get stuck in an endless loop. Make sure each time around the loop you're processing new data!

Answer (score 2):

Since your `catch` is inside the `while` loop, the loop will naturally continue onto the next iteration after the exception has been caught.

Answer (score 1):

Any exception caught in your catch block(s) will not cause the program to terminate.  Simply catch the Exception(s) you want handled and your loop will continue.

```
while(input.hasNextLine())
    try {
        //execute commands by reading them using input.nextLine()
    }
    catch (CargoLoadingException e)
    {
        System.err.println("Can't load cargo while the plane is in flight.");
    }
    catch (OtherException e)
    {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Note that if you catch `Throwable`, you basically catch any exception that can be thrown.  However, you probably only want to catch specific exceptions.  For example, `PlaneCrashException` probably should cause the program to terminate.

Answer (score 1):

The outline you have shown is sufficient to achieve what you want (i.e. the try-catch-construct is inside the while loop). Just make sure that the catch statement declares the correct type or supertype of exception you want to catch-and-ignore.

UPDATE: If you are unsure about what kind of exception to catch, you might want to catch "Throwable", but this is not really recommended. When your teacher had you implement your own exceptions, you probably based them off one existing Exception class. You might want to catch that Exception type then.

And on a totally differnt note, you might want to read in the entirety of the commands from the text file into a list of strings before executing the sequence. This might save you from some IO problems, because you keep the file handle open all the time (which seems unnecessary for such a straight-forward task).

Comment: By leaving the file open, the program could handle data from a socket or other real-time input as well as from a disk file.  Given the file data, this may be how the professor wants the program written.  I agree it is normally best to close a file as fast as you can--grab the data and THEN process it.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the other answers:  Exceptions can do a number of jobs.  All too commonly, they tell you that your program is hopelessly unstable and should shut down immediately.

Normally, they tell you that something bad and unexpected happened, and give you a chance to explain the problem to the user and then carry on.  For instance, an unexpected End-Of-File exception.  You can tell the user the file is bad and let them try another one.  You can also print out a stack trace so they can call you and you can figure out what happened even if you did not print an extensive error message.

Note the split personality of this exception.  Like the first type (RunTimeException instances, usually), they let you know exactly what happened almost without you doing anything.  However, Java also forced you to be aware that an IOException *could* be thrown and tried to force you to write a nice message for the user.  I've always been a bit puzzled about this.  If I catch an EOFException, I *know* where it happened and I don't need the stack trace.  (Of course, if I know an EOF *cannot* happen, I'm not going to bother with a proper message to the user, and the stack trace when it does happen will be very handy.)

But there's a third sort of an exception, sort of the second personality of the previous exception.  It just lets you know something perfectly normal happened.  It is highly efficient (if you set it up right; see below).  And it can be a lot cleaner than returning values up a stack of method calls.  It allows a method that already returns, say, a String (with a null reference being perfectly okay) to alert the calling method to a special condition and, optionally, provide vast amounts of data on that condition.

```
public static class MyEOFException extends EOFException  {
    // Saves creating a meaningless stack trace.
    public Throwable fillInStackTrace()  { return this; }
}
// Saves creating a new object every time you use it
public static MyEOFException  myEOF = new MyEOFException();
```

Then, inside a method:

```
try  {
    for (;;)  {
        String  text = readAStringFromFile( in );
        //  Do something with text...
    }
}
catch (MyEOFException e)  {
    // Nothing at all needs to be done here.
    // Note that MyEOFException COULD have beeen set up with tons of data and
    // then a lot of work could be done.  (The file might end with binary
    // data, for instance, which would be in "e".)
}
```

The exception could be thrown many levels down and it will pop you out of the loop quite neatly.  In most such cases, this would be a little too simplistic.  Often it's too complicated; try-catch blocks can be annoying.  Something like:

```
while (readAStringFromFile( in ));
```

is a lot nicer and faster to write if `readAStringFromFile` has a place to put what it read.

In your particular case, using exeptions like this may be what your professor is looking for.  My personal experience is that there is almost always a better way to do it than with try-catch blocks, but when they do work they work really well.