# how to continue thread execution after getting an exception

Tags: java, exception

```
class TestA implements Runnable {
  public void run() {
    try {
      // do stuff
    } catch(Exception e) {
      // ...
    } finally {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

When an exception occurs, the control comes out of the program. I have 10 files in a `for` loop to be processed.

When there is an exception in the 2nd file, the remaining 8 files do not get processed. But I want a log to be created for the failure and continue processing the remaining files without terminating. Is there any way to do that? Thanks!!!

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490476/java-how-to-continue-reading-a-file-after-an-exception-is-thrown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nest your `try`/`catch` logic inside the `for`-loop:

```
for(...)
{
    try
    {
        ... // process the file
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        ... // deal with the exception
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response. I have read in some forums that using try/catch block inside for loop is not very efficient. Please let me know your thought process on the same. Looking forward for your response! thanks!

Comment: @user1257836: You only have ten files; if a bit of code runs only once for each file, then it runs only ten times. So it doesn't *need* to be "very efficient".

Comment: @user1257836 Using try/catch for flow control is inefficient. Using it to handle exceptional circumstances is not

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I would like to know why using try catch block in for loop is inefficient.

Comment: i will have not more than 10 files but processing those files will take a long time.... please let me know if using the try/catch in such a scenario would be efficient. thanks again!

Comment: @user1257836: The overhead of exception-handling doesn't really depend on how much code is inside the `try` and `catch` blocks. And anyway, it's not as though you had much choice in the matter; this is *the* way to accomplish what you want to do.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. But am still not clear why try catch block inside for loop is inefficient? Please clarify this. thanks in advance!!

Comment: @user1257836: That's an oversimplification. Exception-handling has some overhead; it's more expensive than, say, a loop structure or an conditional structure or a method call. When a `try`/`catch` is nested inside a `for`-loop that runs one-million times per second, you pay that price one-million times per second. But when it's nested inside a `for`-loop that only runs ten times, you only pay that price ten times. And when the contents of the `for`-loop are expensive *anyway* -- and you've indicated that they are -- then the added cost of exception-handling is negligible by comparison.

Comment: @user1257836: By the way, the biggest cost of exception-handling occurs when an exception is actually thrown and caught; whereas I assume that you are *not* expecting most of these files to trigger exceptions.

Comment: I got you now. Thanks a bunch for the explanation! So do we not have any other ways to handle the situation other than try/catch block in for loop.

Comment: Sorry to bother u again. As you have mentioned already in one of your comments , that this is the way to achieve what i want t do. so is this the only way and we do not have other ways to implement this behaviour in java. thanks again!

Comment: @user1257836: I wouldn't say it's the *only* way, but it's *the* way. You might come up with other ways, but you won't come up with any better ones.

Comment: got it!! thanks... i will use this strategy and hope it works out. thanks for responding to all queries!!!

Comment: I am currently trying to get around the issue with using a while loop. It requires to much of the cpu given to my application and freezes all GUI. I assume the for loop do just the same. Is there no other way?

Comment: Also, I tried to create a thread inside a thread. However an excpetion cathced inside thread B (created and started from thread A) stops both threads.

Comment: @Lealo: You haven't given enough information for me (or anyone else) to help you; but you might find [Thread.sleep(long)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) useful.

Comment: I was accidently using if statement instead of while loop. Thats why I though catching exception stopped my thread. Yes thank you I think Thread.sleep(long) will help me!