# Continue Android app after checked exception is thrown

Tags: java, android, exception, try-catch

So I'm trying to parse an numeric input in my EditText box. I'm using Integer parse to parse input into int.

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    int temp;
    try{
        temp=Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
        //do something

    }catch (NumberFormatException e){
        temp=someOtherNumber;
    }
}
```

I want to continue app even if user entered invalid number.
Is that possible?

Comment: Is your application still getting off when `s.toString()` return non numeric value?

Comment: Yes, i mean, it just exits app ( **** suddenly stop responding)...

Comment: But what should i put in finally? Can i leave it empty to continue?

Comment: Is your app is crashing for this exception?? It must not because you handled that exception. I think there should be the other reason....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: How to continue reading a file after an exception is thrown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490476/java-how-to-continue-reading-a-file-after-an-exception-is-thrown)

Comment: You have to catch(Exception e). This will catch any unexpected exceptions have created at runtime.

Comment: Add the whole watcher code here..

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION main

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""

Comment: Cant really copy paste, cause im using AIDE for testing

Comment: Catching the exception and not re-throwing it ensures that the application continues as before. As @PankajKumar mentions, this would imply that you are not showing us the code from where the error is occurring. Either that or the exception being thrown is not a `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: Yeah. Tnx all for posting, my overview... I did have another parse element in method before. I used parseInt in beforeTextChange() method without try/catch block. I thought that because there is always some number by default in EditText box there is no way an exception can occur in beforeTextChange() method...

Answer (score 0):

`NumberFormatException` you should put when you are confident enough that

1.) `Editable s`, `s` is not null. // if not - use `Exception class here`

If that ius not the case, then catching more prcise exception ie. `NumberFormatException` is enough. you have already put a catch block, `so exception will not be propagated`, and you can still continue with your app.

basic Structure

```
try{

// do your stuff here   1

}catch(NumberFormatException nfe){

// do your stuff here   2

}

// do your stuff here    3
```

**Either do your stuff at 1 and 2 both or just at 3**

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""

Comment: Still crushes. I used try/catch block only for parseInt method, put everything else after it, but it still crashes after NumberFormat exception

Comment: @klo are you sure it is crashing in the above code only, i doubt it. code is absolutely fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. Put only catch able code in try catch block. write your remaining code after above catch block.

Comment: Still crushes. I used try/catch block only for parseInt method, put everything else after it, but it still crashes after NumberFormat exception

Comment: Its means you are not catching proper exception.

Answer (score -1):

First check for Editable s it should not null then go further., If you want to catch any exception other than NumberformatException.

then change Catch(NumberFormatException e)  to this  catch (Exception e). If you have any query please let know.

Comment: No its NumberFormat exception. I just want to correct error and continue running...

Comment: and rightly so ... Catching Exception is a terrible advice and a bad practice, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416316/why-is-the-catchexception-almost-always-a-bad-idea for example.